# How to refresh a Visualforce table when the method returns a list

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, pageblocktable

How can I reload a table on a VF page that uses Account as the standard controller? I have an extension as well which supplies the data to the table.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="AccountDimensionViewExtension"> 
    <apex:form id="accountView">     
        <apex:pageBlock title="Primary End Use Market" id="marketList" rendered="{!Account.RecordType.Name='Account'}">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!markets}" var="item">
                <apex:column headervalue="Primary End Use Market" value="{!item.ParentId__r.Name}"/>
                <apex:column headervalue="Primary EUM Sector" value="{!item.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 

        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extension:

```
public class AccountDimensionViewExtension {

    Account account;

    public accountDimensionViewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.account = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        this.account = [Select id, Primary_EUM__c
                        from Account
                        where id = :this.account.id];
    }

    public List<Hierarchy__c> getMarkets() {
        return getPrimaryEUMInfo();
    } 

    public List<Hierarchy__c> getPrimaryEUMInfo() {
            List<Hierarchy__c> subSectorList = [SELECT id, Name, ParentId__c, parentId__r.Name, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate FROM Hierarchy__c WHERE ParentId__c =: this.account.Primary_EUM__c];
            return subSectorList;
    } 
}
```

When I change `Primary_EUM__c` (which is a look up to `Hierarchy__c`) on the account my table doesn't update on save. If I refresh the page then the table does update however ideally I want the VF table to update on save.

I have tried using `PageReference` to force a page refresh but I'm not sure implement it since I need to return `List<Hierarchy__c>` and not `PageReference` so that I have data for the table.

Comment: Is this your complete visualforce code ? Because I can't see the Save `commandButton`. Ideally, you can use the `rerender` attribute of `commandButton` and provide the `id` of your table in that attribute.

Comment: It is all the visualforce code. Because I am using the standard controller I am using the standard buttons also

Comment: For using standard actions as well you need to write the visualforce code so that the buttons appear on the page. Can you confirm if you are able to see the buttons on the page ?

Comment: I can see the buttons on the page. The table in the VF above is only designed to appear like a related list at the bottom of the standard record.

Comment: is this a VF page embedded as a component on the standard Account detail page? How/where does `account.Primary_EUM__c` get changed?